# ayuda java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date hago reporte con fechas

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports, ireport

Quiero hacer un reporte con Java y iReport donde el usuario proporcione las fechas de inicio y fin de la salida de productos en un reporte las fechas las proporciona desde widgets DateTimes y los paso a una variable String y luego esa variable la parseo para que la reconozca ireport pero me he topado con el error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

Aqui dejo el código.

```
String fechaInicio = String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d", dtInicio.getYear(), dtInicio.getMonth() + 1,
                    dtInicio.getDay());
String fechaFin = String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d", dtFin.getYear(), dtFin.getMonth() + 1,
                    dtFin.getDay());        
Map parametro = new HashMap();
Map filtroFecha = new HashMap();

try{
    filtroFecha.put("nomArt", txtArticulo.getText());
    System.out.println(fechaInicio);
    filtroFecha.put("Fecha1", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(fechaInicio).parse(fechaInicio)));
    filtroFecha.put("Fecha2", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(fechaFin).parse(fechaFin)));
    JasperPrint jasperPrintWindow = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                    "reporteFiltroFecha.jasper", filtroFecha,
                    Conexion.GetConnection());
    JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrintWindow,false);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te dice que no puede convertir una cadena en un objeto de tipo fecha

Seguramente tienes configurado tu parametro como `Date`

```
<parameter name="Fecha1" class="java.util.Date"/>
<parameter name="Fecha2" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

Si es asi debes cambiarlo a String

```
<parameter name="Fecha1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="Fecha2" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Esto tambien lo puedes hacer desde el diseñador sin necesidad de editar el xml del `*.jrxml`

---

Recomendación

Puedes dejar tu parametro como `Date` y tu `textField` si tenerlo como string

Para que desde java lo mandes directamente y le des formato desde el reporte

```
filtroFecha.put("Fecha1", fechaInicio));
filtroFecha.put("Fecha2", fechaFin));
```

Y en tu `textField` lo puedes formatear asi

```
<textField>
    <reportElement uuid="764fc239-848c-4329-9e5b-20323a4ced31" x="444" y="5" width="128" height="25"/>
    <textElement>
        <font size="7"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[! $P{FECHA_INICIO}.equals( $P{FECHA_FIN} ) ? new StringBuilder(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MMMM/yyyy", $P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($P{FECHA_INICIO}).toUpperCase() + "-" + new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MMMM/yyyy", $P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($P{FECHA_FIN}).toUpperCase()) : new StringBuilder(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MMMM/yyyy", $P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($P{FECHA_INICIO}).toUpperCase())]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder me has ayudado mucho, me ha servido tu codigo eh cambiado algunos parametros por ahi pero ya quedo mil gracias